# Matrix pipeline stuck waiting to schedule a build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a matrix pipeline that has an agent label with 4 nodes attached to the label. When I try to run my pipeline, the pipeline schedules the job on 4 of the nodes as I wanted but the jobs never end up actually running. They jobs remain scheduled and display the message "**Still waiting to schedule task Waiting for next available executor**".

How can I fix this issue? I have scoured stack overflow and have yet to come up with any sort of solution.

Update: I am including the pipeline along with a screenshot of some of the configuration

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Tests') {
            matrix {
                agent {label 'UH60V && SCADE'}
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'CHOICE'
                        values 'ADC', 'CDU_C', 'DCU', 'DISP_A_REND', 'DISP_PROC', 'EGI', 'FD', 'FLT', 'FMS_C', 'IFF', 'liblO', 'libNGC', 'libSC', 'MISCMP_MP', 'MISCMP_GP', 'NAV_MGR', 'RADALT', 'SYS', 'SYSIO1553', 'SYSIO429', 'SYSRED', 'TACAN', 'VOR_ILS', 'VPA', 'WAAS', 'WCA'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage("Test") {
                        steps {
                            echo "Running ${CHOICE}"
                            build job: "UH60V_SCADE_Suite_Testing", parameters: [string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_PROJECT", value: CHOICE), string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_ACTION", value: "all"), string(name: "CLEARCASE_VIEW_ROOT", value: "myview")] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL2XL.png)

Comment: Are you sure, you have enough Jenkins executor to execute all the job ?

Comment: There are 26 jobs that need to run. Would increasing the number of executors even make a difference with the number of jobs that need to run? The number of executors is currently set to 8.

Comment: If you have 8 executors, I am sure Jenkins should have schedule 8 jobs. If its not happening something wrong on the configuration or pipeline . Could you add some more details to your question like Pipeline , screenshot and etc..

Comment: updated my original post to include the pipeline and a screenshot of some of the configuration